# How to get discount details by coupon code in magento 2 programatily

Tags: magento2, discount

I need to get the details of an already created discount rule in magento 2.

I am using this code but don't work

```
public function __construct(
    \Magento\SalesRule\Model\Coupon $coupon
)
{
    $this->coupon = $coupon;
    parent::__construct($context);
}
```

...

```
public function getDiscount($couponCode)
{
    $ruleId =   $this->coupon->loadByCode($couponCode)->getRuleId();
    return $ruleId;

}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I wasn't that far from the solution:

```
protected $coupon;
protected $saleRule;     

public function __construct(
    \Magento\SalesRule\Model\Coupon $coupon,
    \Magento\SalesRule\Model\Rule $saleRule
)
{
    $this->coupon = $coupon;
    $this->saleRule = $saleRule;
    parent::__construct($context);
}
```

...

```
public function getDiscount($couponCode)
{
    $ruleId =   $this->coupon->loadByCode($couponCode)->getRuleId();
    $rule = $this->saleRule->load($ruleId);
    return $rule->getDiscountAmount();
}
```

Of course need a bit of validation to be sure the rule exist

Answer (score 4):

```
protected $couponModel;

protected $ruleRepository;     

public function __construct(
    \Magento\SalesRule\Model\Coupon $couponModel,
    \Magento\SalesRule\Api\RuleRepositoryInterface $ruleRepository
) {
    $this->couponModel = $coupon;
    $this->ruleRepository = $saleRule;
}


public function getDiscount($couponCode)
{
    $ruleId =  $this->couponModel->loadByCode($couponCode)->getRuleId();
    $rule = $this->ruleRepository->getById($ruleId);
    return $rule->getDiscountAmount();
}
```

Comment: @Price Patel, is it possible to get all coupons collections.Actually i am creating coupons programmatically with skus conditions.now problem is that i am not able to get coupons data(here i want to get skus with coupons).

Comment: @HiteshBalpande Use `Magento\SalesRule\Model\ResourceModel\Rule\Collection` class with `->addFieldToFilter('coupon_type', 2)` to get all coupon collection

Comment: I'd like to give a try on `getList` instead

Comment: @Price Patel, you said `As per Magento 2 coding standards, we should user API interface instead of direct use of the model` so why don't you use `\Magento\SalesRule\Api\Data\CouponInterface` instead of coupon model?

Comment: we dont have any method to get rule data using coupon in CouponInterface @MarceloRodovalho

Comment: Hi @MarceloRodovalho Please check the notes at the end of my answer.

Comment: @PrincePatel how not? I can see the method `getById` in the `Magento\SalesRule\Api\CouponRepositoryInterface`

Comment: @MarceloRodovalho Thank you for bringing it to my attention. There was a typo in the notes. There is no method available in `Magento\SalesRule\Api\CouponRepositoryInterface` to retrieve the rule ID by coupon code. Alternatively, you can utilize the getList method to filter the collection by the coupon code. I will update my answer soon.