# Magento 2: Fetch coupon details from coupon name without applying it to the cart

Tags: magento2, discount

How can I fetch coupon details ie discount amount or percentage from coupon name without applying it to the cart?

Comment: you want coupon collection ?

Comment: You can take reference from https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/220205/how-to-get-discount-details-by-coupon-code-in-magento-2-programatily

Comment: i want to apply coupon on cart items individually for this i want  to fetch coupon details