# How to get Coupon Name from Coupon Code

Tags: magento2

I want to get my Coupon name from the Coupon code, but whenever I try to `loadByCode` it always return me an error null message

my code

```
use Magento\Quote\Api\CouponManagementInterface;
use Magento\SalesRule\Model\Coupon;
use Magento\SalesRule\Model\Rule;

public function __construct(
        CouponManagementInterface $couponManagement,
        Coupon $Coupon,
        Rule $saleRule
    ) {
        $this->couponManagement = $couponManagement;
        $this->Coupun = $Coupon;
        $this->saleRule = $saleRule;
    }

    public function resolve(Field $field, $context, ResolveInfo $info, array $value = null, array $args = null)
    {
        if (!isset($value['model'])) {
            throw new LocalizedException(__('"model" value should be specified'));
        }
        $quote = $value['model'];
        $cartId = $quote->getId();
        $appliedCoupons = [];
        $appliedCoupon = $this->couponManagement->get($cartId);
        if ($appliedCoupon) {
            $appliedCoupons[] = [ 'code' => $appliedCoupon ];
        }
        $writer = new \Zend\Log\Writer\Stream(BP . '/var/log/diskon.log');
        $logger = new \Zend\Log\Logger();
        $logger->addWriter($writer);
         // In here the function return the error message
        $logger->info( $this->Coupon->loadByCode($appliedCoupon)->getRuleId());
    }
```

Does anyone know how to get the Coupon name from Salesrule? Thank you

Comment: try this https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/220251/82670

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below code will work for get Rule Name

> $logger->info(
> $this->Coupon->loadByCode($appliedCoupon)->getRuleName());